# Component display issues in Laravel Wizard form

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the Wizard form to join several form pages so that it is possible to create a record, however in the page `page1.blade.php` method the `Next` button is not showing as it should not JS from `main.blade.php` page, how do I solve this? In short: **the JS code doesn't work**.

- `main.blade.php`

```
@extends('templates.template_hunter')
@section('title', 'Main')

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Form') }}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('submitForm')}}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div id="page1" class="form-page">
                                @include('page1')
                            </div>
                            <div id="page2" class="form-page d-none">
                                @include('page2')
                            </div>
                            <div id="page3" class="form-page d-none">
                                @include('page3')
                            </div>
                            <div id="page4" class="form-page d-none">
                                @include('page4')
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <button id="prevButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary d-none">Previous</button>
                               <button id="nextButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                               <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success d-none">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        var current_page = 1;
        var max_page = 4;

        function changePage(page_number) {

            var current_page_element = document.getElementById("page" + current_page);
            var next_page_element = document.getElementById("page" + page_number);

            current_page_element.classList.add("d-none");
            next_page_element.classList.remove("d-none");

            current_page = page_number;

            if (current_page == 1) {
                document.getElementById("prevButton").classList.add("d-none");
            } else {
                document.getElementById("prevButton").classList.remove("d-none");
            }

            if (current_page == max_page) {
                document.getElementById("submitButton").classList.remove("d-none");
                document.getElementById("nextButton").classList.add("d-none");
            } else {
                document.getElementById("submitButton").classList.add("d-none");
                document.getElementById("nextButton").classList.remove("d-none");
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("nextButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (current_page < max_page) {
                changePage(current_page + 1);
            }
        });

        document.getElementById("prevButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (current_page > 1) {
                changePage(current_page - 1);
            }
        });

    </script>

@endsection
```

- `web.php`

```
Route::get('/main', [HunterController::class, 'main'])->name('main');
Route::post('/main', [HunterController::class, 'submitForm'])->name('submitForm');
```

- `page1.blade.php`

```
@extends('templates.template_hunter')
@section('title', 'Register Hunter (Part I)')

@section('content')

    <div class="contained">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

- `page2.blade.php`

```
@extends('templates.template_hunter')
@section('title', 'Register Hunter (Part II)')

@section('content')

    <div class="contained">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

- `page3.blade.php`

```
@extends('templates.template_hunter')
@section('title', 'Register Hunter (Part III)')

@section('content')

    <div class="contained">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

- `page4.blade.php`

```
@extends('templates.template_hunter')
@section('title', 'Register Hunter (Part IV)')

@section('content')

    <div class="contained">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Why not using js wizard ? https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-5-simple-multi-step-form-33401608